# Uniformly convergent in a set implies uniformly convergent in the set closure, too.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $f_n$:$X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions uniformly convergent in $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$  . Suppose that each $f_n$ is continuous in the closure of $X$. Then $f_n$ is also uniformly convergent in the closure of $X$.

Proof: I'm just gonna "talk it", to avoid boring with espsilon, deltas,etc.: From some N onwards the plots of the functions $f_n$ are very closed between them, at least in $X$. If we take a point $y$ in the closure, but not in the set, that point occurs to be a cluster point. Now, taking two functions with index bigger than N, call them $f_p$ and $f_r$, they both are continuous at $y$, and we can find a neighborhood of $y$ in which $f_p(l)$ is very near to $f_p(y)$, forall $l$ in that neighborhood. Analogous with $f_r$. Taking an element of $X$ in the more little neighborhood, we see that the images of that element through $f_p$ and $f_r$ are pretty closed between them. It follows that $f_r(y)$ and $f_p(y)$ are also pretty near. Since $r,p$ were arbitrarily taken bigger than $N$, we get that $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the closure, and so converges uniformly.

Is it right?A simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\epsilon$ and $N$s provides a simpler proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ then choose $N$ such that for $n,m \ge N$ we have
$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x \in X$.

Choose $\bar{x} \in \bar{X}$, then there are $x_k \in X$ such that $x_k \to \bar{x}$. Since the $f_i$ are continuous, we see that
$f_m(x_k) \to f_m(\bar{x})$ and similarly for $n$. Hence the above inequality
holds for $\bar x$, that is
$|f_n(\bar{x})-f_m(\bar{x})| \le \epsilon$ for all $\bar{x} \in \bar{X}$.