# Can we approximate uniformly a function defined on a subset with smooth functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, approximation, uniform-convergence, singularity

Let $\mathbb{D}^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the **closed** $n$-dimensional unit ball. Suppose we are given an **open** subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{D}^n$ of **full measure** in $\mathbb{D}^n$, and a smooth **bounded** function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$.

> Do there exist smooth functions $f_k:\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which converge **uniformly** to $f$?

Note that that the derivatives of the original $f$ may explode when we approach $\partial U$. In my specific case $U$ has Hausdorff dimension $\le n-1$, but I am not sure if it matters.

Comment: Is sin(1/x) without the origin a counter example?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned by Elad](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314897/can-we-approximate-uniformly-a-function-defined-on-a-subset-with-smooth-function#comment6820055_3314897) $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ is a counter-example.

Indeed, suppose that $f_k:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$. Then $f_k$ [converges uniformly on the closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1649851/104576) $\text{cl}([-1,1]\setminus\{0\} )=[-1,1]$. This implies that the limit is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$, which is a contradiction. (as $\sin(1/x)$ cannot be extended to a continuous function on $[-1,1]$).